# Recorrer array objetos y operar

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Buen dia,

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio que no he dado como resolverlo.

En una empresa se empacan cajas entre N numero de personas, a todas se les paga por igual desde y cuando todos cumplan con la jornada, por ejemplo, si son 3 personas, y empacan 100 cajas, le corresponde pagar el valor de empaque por igual pues cada uno empacó 33.33 cajas, entonces si el valor de la caja lo pagan a $1 dolar, pues cada uno recibiría $33.33 dolares

tengo esto lo tengo en un array de objetos llamado formato_empaque

```
var formato_empaque =[{nombre:"Juan",cajas_empacadas:0,descuento_cajas=0},{nombre:"Maria",cajas_empacadas:0,descuento_cajas=0},{nombre:"Juan",cajas_empacadas:0,descuento_cajas=0}]
```

los atributos descuento_cajas, estan organizados de mayor a menor

en este caso son 3 trabajadores, ninguno tuvo descuentos de cajas, entonces facilmente recorro el array de objetos y divido

```
for(var i = 0; i<formato_empaque.length; i++)
  { 
    if(formato_empaque[0]['descuento_cajas']==0)
    {

      //como descuento_cajas esta organizado de mayor a menor, al tener 0 descuento en la posicion 0, quiere decir que todos estuvieron en la jornada, es decir no hubo descuentos
      
//actualizo entonces las claves cajas_empacadas de los objetos en este caso con 33.33 unidades
      formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas']=(total_cajas_empacadas/cantidad_trabajadores);       
    }
}
```

Hasta aqui es sencillo pues simplemente se divide el total de cajas entre el numero de trabajadores pues no hubo descuentos

pero puede pasar lo siguiente, que un trabajador se fue en una parte de la jornada laboral por que digamos que tuvo una emergencia en casa y no estuvo presente en 20 cajas, entonces a el le corresponden (80 cajas / 3) y a los otros les corresponde eso mismo + (20 cajas que faltaron en las que no estuvo el primero / 2), es decir el primero tendrá 26.6 cajas y los otros dos tendran 36.6 cajas, de tal manera que la suma de cada uno da 100 cajas empacadas entre los tres

el array de objetos esta organizado de mayor a menor por el atributo descuento_caja, en este caso sería asi

var formato_empaque =[{nombre:"Juan",cajas_empacadas:0,descuento_cajas=20},{nombre:"Maria",cajas_empacadas:0,descuento_cajas=0},{nombre:"Juan",cajas_empacadas:0,descuento_cajas=0}]

donde
en la posicion 0 del array clave descuento_cajas = 20
en la posicion 1 del array clave descuento_cajas = 0
en la posicion 2 del array clave descuento_cajas = 0

tambien puede pasar que el segundo se fue despues del primero, es por esto que el array de objetos lo ordené de mayor a menor por el atributo descuento cajas, de esta manera el primero gana menos dinero que el segundo y el segundo menos que el tercero

la cuestion es que debe funcionar para N numero de trabajadores, en la parte del for donde itero los objetos, lo llevo asi, con un remanente, pero no me gunciona, alguna idea?

```
if(formato_empaque[0]['descuento_cajas_trabajador']==0)
    {
      //aqui quiere decir que ninguno tuvo descuentos pues el array de objetos se ordenó por descuento_cajas_trabajador de mayor a menor
      //entonces si la posicion 0 de esa clave es 0 es por que nadie tuvo descuentos

      console.log("total cajas empacadas="+total_cajas_empacadas);
      console.log("cantidad trabajadores="+cantidad_trabajadores);
      formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas_trabajador']=(total_cajas_empacadas/cantidad_trabajadores).toFixed(2);      
      console.log("cajas empacadas posicion"+i+"="+formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas_trabajador']);      
    }
    else{      
      //aqui quiere decir que hubo descuentos, al menos 1
      //var descuento_cajas_trabajador=formato_empaque[i]['descuento_cajas_trabajador'];
      if(formato_empaque[i]['descuento_cajas_trabajador']>0)
      {       
        remanente = remanente + formato_empaque[i]['descuento_cajas_trabajador'];
        if(remanente>0)
        {
          cantidad_trabajadores = cantidad_trabajadores-1;
          formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas_trabajador'] = (parseInt(total_cajas_empacadas)-parseInt(descuento_cajas_trabajador)+parseInt(remanente))/cantidad_trabajadores;
        }
        else{
          formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas_trabajador']=(parseInt(total_cajas_empacadas)-parseInt(descuento_cajas_trabajador))/cantidad_trabajadores;
        }
         
        
          //console.log("cajas empacadas posicion"+i+"="+formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas_trabajador']);
          
        
      }
    }      
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hubo varios errores en los ejemplos que pegaste, la verdad no creo que ese codigo haya sido tuyo, pero de todas formas el ejercicio esta entretenido asi que ahi va, no hace falta evaluar el descuento de las cajas con un if, eso lo debes hacer en un solo calculo, y con la ayuda de la variable remanente, podes saber cuantas cajas quedan por hacer mediante la resta del total, menos lo realizado hasta el momento, quedaría algo asi;

```js
var formato_empaque = [
{nombre:"Juan",   cajas_empacadas:0,  descuento_cajas:0},
{nombre:"Maria",  cajas_empacadas:0,  descuento_cajas:1},
{nombre:"Juan",   cajas_empacadas:0,  descuento_cajas:0}];

var total_cajas_empacadas = 100;
var cantidad_trabajadores = formato_empaque.length;
var remanente = 0.0;

console.log("Cantidad trabajadores = " + cantidad_trabajadores);
console.log("Total cajas empacadas = " + total_cajas_empacadas);
console.log("")

for(var i = 0; i<formato_empaque.length; i++) {
    // a modo de facilitar la legibilidad metemos este valor en una variable
    var des_cajas = parseInt(formato_empaque[i]['descuento_cajas']);

    console.log("Empleado : " + formato_empaque[i].nombre);

    // se calcula la cantidad de cajas empacadas
    formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas'] = ( (total_cajas_empacadas - remanente - des_cajas) / (cantidad_trabajadores - i) ).toFixed(2);

    // la cantiad de cajas empacadas para restarselo en la siguiente iteracion
    remanente += Number(formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas']);

    console.log("Cajas empacadas = " + formato_empaque[i]['cajas_empacadas'] + " hechas " + remanente);
    console.log("")
}
```

Con este código, podes agregar la cantidad de empleados que creas necesario, y siempre a medida de evalua a cada uno, sabrá cuantas cajas quedan por hacer, para repartirlas entre los restantes.

Comment: Gracias Javier! muy util tu ayuda